# Add new custom layoutSlot to home page template

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I need to add two new layouySlots (cx-page-layout) to the home page.
What is the best way to do this? I have read that a custom root component (cx-storefront) should be implemented but I have not found any working example to follow.
Can anyone help me please? Where do i find a tutorial?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you want to add `cx-page-layout` instead of `cx-page-slot`?

Comment: Hi Michal, yes, for me the best solution would be to add a layout slot (cx-page-layout) outside the header (before) and another just after the footer.
But it's not clear to me if I can only do this by passing a custom LayoutConfig to my angular module or should I use cx-header outlet references. As far as I understand the two modes cannot be used together: one excludes the other. It's true?

Comment: I don't know if it can be set from the backend, but I don't see anything against overwriting `StorefrontComponent` with your own template contains this additional `cx-page-layout`. It looks like little workaround, but let me confirm.